# Gerund vs infinitive: ‘suggested to me {to get/getting}’

Tags: grammaticality, gerund-vs-infinitive

Can I know which one is correct. I am confused about when to use gerund/infinitive in a sentence.

1. My brother suggested to me **to get** a job in bank
2. My brother suggested to me **getting** a job in bank.

Can anyone explain the concept of gerund/infinitive in some detail if possible?

Comment: It seems are if you are learning English. If so, then our sister site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) would probably be more suited to your questions.  I'm voting to move this question accordingly.

Comment: @TrevorD I am also a learner, so take that with a pinch of salt, but I don't see a grammatical mistake in either example. It's simply a question about usage.

Comment: My brother suggested I get a job in a bank.

Comment: This must be a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic phrase would use indirect speech, I guess.

> My Brother suggested I get a job
>
> My Brother suggested to me that I get a Job

Concerning your examples, *to get* is a verb, and the phrase "suggest to" is frequent enough. In principle it should be OK to follow that by "to me" as that's where indirect objects go, while the suggesting is perceived as the direct object of *to suggest*. But two times *to* in a row doesn't flow nicely. The gerund is somewhere between a noun and a verb, but the nominal of the suggestion is the target, a job, not the getting. So better would be *my brother suggested jobbing*, but I'm not sure how the dativ pronoun (*whom?*) fits in. Whether to-infinitive or gerund does depend on the usage of the specific word in question, and it seems the to-infinitive is downright proscribed (e.g. [1](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/how-to-use-the-english-verb-suggest/), [2](https://www.phrasemix.com/answers/how-do-you-use-suggest-correctly)).